# What is the problem with my code using strchr

Tags: c++

I want to deal with the character(operator) to operate some numbers. But the point is the character is from the stack. When I declare the Char-type stack and get the character(operator) by using top() method, it doesn't work in strchr function.. I don't know why.. I really want to know how to fix it, and what is wrong.

This is in C++ programming.

This is my main code

```
int main() {
    string c;

    stack<char> postfix_expression;


    double result = 0;

    postfix_expression.push('+');
    postfix_expression.push('1');
    postfix_expression.push('3');


    result = read_and_evaluate(postfix_expression);

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my read_and_evaluate function..

```
double read_and_evaluate(stack<char>& arithmetic_expression ){

    stack<double> numbers;
    for(int i =0; i < arithmetic_expression.size() ; ++i){
        char c = arithmetic_expression.top();
        if (isdigit(c)){
            numbers.push((double)c - 48);
            cout << (int)c - 48 << endl;
        }else if(strchr("+-*/", c) != NULL){
            evaluate_stack(numbers, c);
            cout << c << endl;
            cout << numbers.top() << endl;
        }
        arithmetic_expression.pop();
    }
    return numbers.top();
}
```

This is evaluate_stack function

```
void evaluate_stack(stack<double>& operands, char operators) {
    double operand2 = operands.top();
    operands.pop();
    double operand1 = operands.top();
    operands.pop();

    switch(operators) {
        case '+':
            operands.push(operand1 + operand2);
        case '-':
            operands.push(operand1 - operand2);
        case '*':
            operands.push(operand1 * operand2);
        case '/':
            if (operand2 != 0.0)
                operands.push(operand1 / operand2);
            else {
                cout << "Error!: divide by zero\n";
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
    cout << operands.top() << endl;
}
```

It is about postfix expression. I want to get 3 1 + 4 for results.
But it just shows 3 1 1.

Comment: Please post the code for `evaluate_stack`.

Comment: You need to give us enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: There is a goat in line 13 of `evaluate_stack`.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to mind the evaluate_stack because the point is when the variable c in read_and_evaluate function is '+', strchr function doesn't work. I will update the code, Thank you for the comments, and afraid of the not enough explaination.

Comment: @SangilMo, try my suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a heads up.

```
for(int i =0; i < arithmetic_expression.size() ; ++i){

    ...

    arithmetic_expression.pop();
}
```

is logically incorrect. When you pop the top of the stack, size of the stack goes down by 1. By incrementing `i` and comparing it with the size of the stack, you will end up ignoring half of the stack. You can fix that by using:

```
// There is no need for i
for ( ; arithmetic_expression.size() > 0; arithmetic_expression.pop()) {

   ...

}
```